# MongoDB 'Manually Sharding' for multi-tenancy

Tags: mongodb, multi-tenant, saas

We are using Mongo to host a multi-tenant application. Each tenant is going to have their own database. To get around resource utilization issues the approach that we are taking is to shard by database (as opposed to by collection - if that is the correct term to use).

This means for every x tenants we will create a new 3-node replica set. So we may have for example 1000 tenants on 1 shard and another 1000 tenants on another shard.

My question is regarding the placement of the databases for new signups. The approach we were going to take was to flag a shard as being the 'active' shard and creating all new tenants on that shard. When it reaches capacity, create a new shard, flag that as the active shard and continue on.

Can you choose which shard you create a new database on in Mongo directly? If left to Mongo, from what I understand, it will do it in round robin fashion when there is more then one shard which may leave our shards imbalanced.

Is this the right approach or is there an alternative better approach?

Comment: If the shard key is the 'tenant id', and this id is a simple  increasing counter, with new tenants always having higher numbers than older ones, then I think the behavior you describe should happen automatically

Comment: Isn't the shard key defined at the collection level? That being the case, the database identifier is what is going to distinguish the tenants (Having a different tenant ID as part of the database name) and not the shard key. Since we aren't sharding by collection I don't see how that would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [shard tags](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/tag-aware-sharding/) to force some collections to reside only on specific shards. So you could, for example, tag each shard with its serial number, and tag the collections/databases you want to have on that shard with that tag, until it runs full at which point you create a new shard, increase the counter and use that for new data.

Another option then is to not enable sharding on the individual databases at all, and use the [movePrimary](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/movePrimary/) command to force a specific shard to act as the primary shard for a specific database. Since the database won't be sharded, all its data will remain on its designated primary shard, which is exactly what you want.

That being said, it seems to me like this approach conflicts with the very concept of sharding, which is meant to evenly distribute data across multiple machines automatically.